# GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter details, & polylines

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to get list_location.get(i).getLatitude() on loc.setText problem is that it loops and get the last latitude, add button problem dismiss is not working and how to add polylines on each marker once I click the button?

Here is my code:

```
     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (i = 0; i < list_location.size(); i++) {
                    createMarker(i, list_location.get(i).getLatitude(), list_location.get(i).getLongitude(), list_location.get(i).getLocation());
                }
            }
            });
        return v;
    }

    private void createMarker(int index, String latitude, String longitude, String snippet) {
        // Adding the taped point to the ArrayList
        BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        Double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
        Double Longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

/*        float color = 0;
        if (index == 1)
            color = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE;
        else if (index == list_location.size()-1)
            color = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET;*/

        if (index == 1)
            image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
        else if (index == list_location.size()-1)
            image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_slideshow);
        else {
            image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        }

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat, Longitude))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .title("title")
                .snippet(list_location.get(i).getLatitude())
                .icon(image));

        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View myContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.marker_popup, null);
                TextView loc = ((TextView) myContentView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView2));
                TextView plate_num = ((TextView) myContentView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView4));
                loc.setText(marker.getTitle());
                plate_num.setText(marker.getSnippet());
/*                for (int i = 0; i < list_location.size(); i++) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "getLatitude:" + list_location.get(i).getLatitude() + " getLongitude:" + list_location.get(i).getLongitude());
                    if (marker.getSnippet().equals(list_location.get(i).getLocation())) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Selected Marker");
                    }

                }*/

                Button btnDismiss = (Button) myContentView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
                btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                return myContentView;
            }
        });
```

Comment: In `list_location.get(i)` from where are you getting `i`. I think it should be `index` as per your code inside `createMarker`

Comment: Hi, thank you for that answer. That makes any changes. It has the same result. Can you help me in writing the correct windowAdapter for my popUp Details I want it on loc.setText. Also, how may I add a line using the coordinates on for loop once I click the button.. Thanks